# CloudWatch log role ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to setup a really basic API with the AWS **API Gateway** product and it seems I can not find any policies which will suffice for it to log and for that matter even leave the first page of the settings screen. I am stuck here:

URL: `https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region=eu-west-1#/settings`

and my desperations has led to the following permissions being granted to the role:

[image]

I've also added the following bespoke policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

All to no avail. Whenever I press the save button I get the following:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually an error with API Gateway not being able to assume that specific role.
This is probably due to your role's Trust Relationship policy not allowing the API Gateway Service to assume the role.

If you add the following Trust Relationship policy, it should work:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: perfect. you're my hero.

Comment: I have attached this policy and now get this error "An error occurred: Policy document should not specify a principal."

Comment: Hi rkaltreider - this is a Trust Relationship policy - rather than a typical IAM policy attached to a User/Group:

For example - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-sharing-logs-third-party.html

Comment: Oops I already had "trust relationship" with the role BUT with principal service `"event.amazonaws.com"` not `apigateway.amazonaws.com`. So changing service to `apigateway.amazonaws.com` works