# CloudWatch log role ARN and Policy

Tags: logging, role, cloudwatch

A question was asked on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852878/cloudwatch-log-role-arn/38546027#38546027) about CloudWatch log role ARN and an answer was provided that the following Trust Relationship policy would allow for enabling CloudWatch logs. My question is, *where* do I place this policy? Trying to add it by going to IAM --> Policies --> Crate Policy --> Creating your own policy, produces an error that reads "This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal." Where do I create this policy to make Cloud Watch logs to work? Below is the solution given in the [page I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852878/cloudwatch-log-role-arn/38546027#38546027).

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create an IAM user. Create an IAM role instead and attach the `AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs` policy.

Then under the role, you can change the `Trust Relationships` and add this.